# CakePHP Auth Component Want to Check User Only Dont Want to Login

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I am using two step registration on my site. If a user has only done first part of registration and left registration. Next time if user try to login i just want him/her to redirect on 2nd step of registration.

So when user will enter email and password with auth component i just want to check that the user and password he entered is valid, i dont want to login user.

When i put $this->Auth->login() in code, it directly login the user if credentials are right.

**I don't want user to login and then make it logout and redirect to step 2 registration.**

Comment: Please provide a code sample connected with your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [AuthComponent::identify()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-AuthComponent.html#_identify)?

Instead of passing the post data to `AuthComponent::login()`, pass it to `AuthComponent::identify()`.

If you get a user back from calling the latter, you can check in the returned array the level of registration (assuming you store it there, which you probably should).

If it is a fully registered user, proceed to login that user by passing the user information in `AuthComponent::login($user)` (you shouldn't ask them to login twice). If not redirect them to your second level of the registration.

If you get false from `identify()` the user either got his details wrong or doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeah, Thank you its working. Sorry i don't know how to mark your answer correct.

Comment: I'm glad I helped. To mark a question as accepted, go to the left side of the question under the up/down buttons and [press on the gray tick](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)